# Images not loading after building ionic application on my Android phone

Tags: html, css, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I downloaded the apk of my ionic application on my phone however the images appear to be broken (broken image icon appears instead of real image).

I have already tried adding   `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>` to my config file.

and added in the index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

this is my image code in the view which comes from the json

```
<img ng-src="{{jobData.logo_url}}" style=" display: block;width:100px;height:auto;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" />
```

this is the image link:

```
 <img ng-src="//s3.amazonaws.com/JHP-S3/uploads/image/150327/isqcqVhFUh/plogo" style=" display: block;width:100px;height:auto;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/JHP-S3/uploads/image/150327/isqcqVhFUh/plogo">
```

this is what is returned from the json

```
 "banner_url":"\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/JHP-S3\/uploads\/image\/90872\/bjyOWgvuN8\/pbanner",
```

Comment: try after add `http:` at start of url

Comment: @Divyesh Savaliya thank you, that worked :)